# When click on title, make information appear on another div for the information?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click

I'm  looking for a jQuery solution for this. When I click, let's say on a artist name. Theirs another div beside that has the information showing up. (possibly in a animation/fading way)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Link and Info Within Physical Proximity

Use this method if your artist link and artist info is within physical proximity (i.e., sibling in the DOM). Let's say you have:

```
<a ... class="artistInfo">Artist name</a>
<div class="artistInfo"> .... shown on link click </div>

... repeat
```

Then use:

```
$('div.artistInfo').hide(); // Initially hide info
$('a.artistLink').click(function() { // Show on click
    $(this).next('div.artistInfo').fadeIn();
});
```

`next()` is used to avoid wrapping each link-info set in "per-artist" container. Thus, you should be able to have multiple "sets" of link-plus-info in the same page.

## Link and Info in Different Places

When there is no physical proximity between the link and tha info, you will need *some* sort of identifiers from the link to the info*. E.g.,

```
<a ... class="artistLink" id="artistLink-1">Artist name</a>

... 

<div class="artistInfo" id="artistInfo-1"> .... shown on link click </div>
```

You can now:

```
$('div.artistInfo').hide(); // Initially hide all infos
$('a.artistLink').click(function() { // Show on click (by reference)
    var n = $(this).attr('id').substring(11); // Remove "artistLink-"
    $('#artistInfo' + n).fadeIn();
});
```

---

*) *Note*: You *could* use the DOM index if links and infos are ordered similarly. I.e., the *n*th `<a>` element corresponds to the *n* info element.

Comment: This seems to work for me. But the titles and the information isn't gonna be in the same div. 2 different positions of the page. And their's more then one artist. How can I add  more artists and information without it messing up? Im OP

Answer (score 0):

Use the [.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method of jquery

Answer (score 0):

If by 'beside' you mean it is the very next sibling, you can use [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$(".artist").click(function() {
    $(this).next("div").slideToggle("slow");
});

<span class="artist">Foo and the Jackals</span>
<div>some content</div>

<span class="artist">Jeff and the misshapen lunatics</span>
<div>some content</div>

...
```

[`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) will "Display or hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.".

Answer (score 0):

There can be a number of ways to do this. But then it actually depends on how exactly you want it. one possible way can be use of fadeIn method on a hidden DIV.

`<div class='box' style="display:none;">
 <p> Artist Description </p>
</div>`

<p id='abcd'>Artist Name</p>

for example on this code use this jquery

`jQuery('#abcd').click(function(){
jQuery('.box').fadeIn();
});`